# Append then delete but dont delete the last input text or row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have this simple append and then remove i can remove it all but the problem is how can i disable remove if their is only one remaining input text?

my **remove jQuery Script**

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".remove",function(){
  var doc = jQuery(this);
  var remove = doc.closest(".list");
  var del = jQuery(".remove").length;
  if(del < 1){
    remove.remove();
  }         
});
```

if you need other details just in case here is the **HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="list"><input type="text"> <a href="#" class="remove">x</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <a href="#" class="add">Add</a> <a href="#" class="save">Save</a>
  </body>
```

and **ADD jQuery Script**

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".add",function(){
    var counter = jQuery(".list").length;
    var add = "<li class='list'><input type='text'> <a href='#' class='remove'>x</a></li>";
    if(counter < 10){                   
        jQuery("ul").append(add);
    }else{
        alert("Maximum is 10.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the less than to greater than in your remove handler.

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".remove",function(){
    var doc = jQuery(this);
    var remove = doc.closest(".list");
    var del = jQuery(".remove").length;
    if(del > 1){
        remove.remove();
    }         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = 1;

$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
    call your add function
    count++;
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    if(count > 1)
    {
        call your delete function
        count --;
    }
});
```

Comment: if i do this i cant reset the count per list display for example i have 10 list then i remove 1 but the count is still 10 not become 9.

Comment: what i want is minimum of 1 and maximum of 10 list or input.